# Qt Creator not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, snap, qt

I've installed the program Qt Creator using the package manager (Using `sudo apt install qtcreator`. After installing when I try to launch the program, it gives the following error message.

```
qtcreator: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried doing `sudo apt install libqt5widgets5` but that shows it's already installed.

When I ran `locate libQt5Widgets.so.5`,
these came up:

```
/snap/kde-frameworks-5/27/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5
/snap/kde-frameworks-5/27/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.11
/snap/kde-frameworks-5/27/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5.11.0
```

The result of `apt-cache policy qtcreator`:

```
qtcreator:
  Installed: 4.5.2-3ubuntu2
  Candidate: 4.5.2-3ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 4.5.2-3ubuntu2 500
        500 http://mirror.dhakacom.com/ubuntu-archive bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

And `snap list` :

```
Name                  Version    Rev   Tracking  Publisher  Notes
core                  16-2.34.3  5145  stable    canonical  core
gnome-3-26-1604       3.26.0     70    stable/…  canonical  -
gnome-calculator      3.28.2     180   stable/…  canonical  -
gnome-characters      3.28.2     103   stable/…  canonical  -
gnome-logs            3.28.2     37    stable/…  canonical  -
gnome-system-monitor  3.28.2     51    stable/…  canonical  -
gtk-common-themes     0.1        319   stable    canonical  -
kde-frameworks-5      5.47.0     27    stable    kde        -
okular                18.04.2    33    stable    kde        -
termdown              1.13.0     8     stable    dpb        -
```

I'm fairly new to Linux and Ubuntu. I can't seem to find any particular solutions online. My system is Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (64 bit).

**UPDATE:**
After searching online a little I did the following

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libqt5widgets5
```

And that changed the warning to error while loading shared libraries: "something else" cannot open .....
So I kept reinstalling the libraries causing errors and now this came,

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried reinstalling multiple times but that didn't help.

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. Did you installed QtCreator from APT (`sudo apt-get install qtcreator`)? Please add output of `apt-cache policy qtcreator` and `snap list` to the question.

Comment: Yes, I installed using `sudo apt install qtcreator`. Also I've added the information as requested. @N0rbert

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue having installed same Snaps and qtcreator from deb-package (by APT) on clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Please add output of `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5 | grep not`, `which qtcreator` and `export  | grep -E "^LD|LIB"` to the question. Is it clean install?

Comment: I ran in the same issue as yours. Qt Creator would not start in Ubuntu 18.04.   sudo apt install --reinstall libqt5widgets5  resolved the matter for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tedious surfing on the internet I eventually found the solution myself. I believe my issue was due to this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1772900
as my installation also failed during grub install and probably is an incomplete installation.
Due to this many libraries were marked as installed but not actually installed (thus causing the missing library errors). This not only effected Qt creator but other applications like VLC, Gparted, etc. 
So my solution mostly involved reinstalling all missing libraries (shown in errors and found using `ldd`). And eventually I got it to work.